# locking Excel worksheet that has macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have locked couple of cells and the worksheet and I have a macro for the worksheet but I can't find a way to lock the worksheet and run the macros at the same time. Everytime i try to run the macro while it's locked gives me an error.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim g As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim overallhealth As Range
Dim varaincerange As Range
Set varaincerange = Sheets("D").Range("B5:B9")
Set overallhealth = Sheets("D").Range("B4")
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(varaincerange, "y")
g = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(varaincerange, "g")
r = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(varaincerange, "r")
If g = 5 Then
overallhealth = "G"
ElseIf g = 4 And y = 1 Then
overallhealth = "G"
ElseIf r >= 2 Then
overallhealth = "R"
ElseIf y = 1 And r = 1 Then
overallhealth = "Y"
ElseIf y > 1 And r >= 1 Then
overallhealth = "R"
ElseIf y = 1 And r > 1 Then
overallhealth = "R"
ElseIf y >= 3 Then
overallhealth = "R"
ElseIf g = 3 And y = 2 Then
overallhealth = "Y"
ElseIf g = 4 And r = 1 Then
overallhealth = "Y"
End If
End Sub
```

How can i run the macro while the cells and the worksheet is locked and protected?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply unprotect it at the beginning of your macro with

```
Sheets("D").Unprotect "password"
```

and at the end reprotect it with

```
Sheets("D").Protect "password"
```

Comment: Hi, sorry it still gives me the 1004 error. when i unlock the worksheet the macro runs fine, but when i use the code above to lock the worksheet, it gives me a 1004 error.

Comment: are you sure it happens in the line with the `.Protect`? and if so, is the name of the worksheet correct?

Comment: Yes i've double checked but it still gives me a 1004 error. i'm assuming it's giving this error because of the locked cells....?

Comment: So if you step through the code (set a breakpoint in the first row with F9 and the pres F8 for each step), does it cause the error in the last line? If so, can you protect the sheet manually? Try the macro recorder and see what code it generates...

Comment: Second thought: add `Application.EnableEvents = False` to the top of your code - and `Application.EnableEvents = True` to the end. This way you prevent potential endless loops (esp. if you have another Worksheet_Change event)